# how to tackle asynchronous problems in React

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs

I am new to React.

I have been experimenting a lot and most of the times I run into situations which run asynchronously.

For ex:

I have this problem where I need to call a function to perform some actions based on the states before render gets called.

The states are updated based on the props passed on.

Currently I use componentWillReceiveProps.The code looks something like this.

```
_function(){
    //uses state variables.
},
componentWillReceiveProps: function (){
   this.setState({
        ......
   });

   _function();

},
```

This is going async and I have run onto these kind of issues many times.

How to tackle above situation and what are the good practices so that I won't run into async issues.

Any good references would definitely help.

Comment: Is your issue that _function() is being called before this.setState finishes? You can provide _function as a callback to setState (e.g., this.setState({}, _function)).  Also if you have stuff that needs to be done immediately before rendering, then I think you should use componentWillUpdate.

Comment: @james I have tried this.But the callback was never called.

Comment: hmm, maybe you need to bind it? e.g., this.setState({...}, _function.bind(this))

Answer (score 0):

generally you don't.

react just renders views.  write a vanilla js application that handles your async stuff, then push the results into your view with a new `react.render`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass nextProps to the function that needs new state.

```
    _function(nextProps){
            //uses state variables.
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps){
         this.setState({
                    ......
         });

         _function(nextProps);

    },
```